# accidental wipe android nexus 4

Tags: adb, nexus-4

Well, accidentally ended up formatting a nexus 4 by clockworkmod, was the system and everything else, I've tried various ways to try to recover this brink, worked no more, all require the famous usb debugging, plus he has no system and windows no longer see it as an external drive to be able to put an image on it, and is it ..

obs.: I still have access to recovery

Grateful for now and sorry my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get to recovery you should be able to flash the full factory image which will restore your phone to completely stock.

Download the full [occam factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occamjwr66v), which includes the full system, bootloader, recovery, kernel (boot.img), and radio. It's a clean slate for these components - they'll flash cleanly over anything you have now.

You can run the bundled script called flash-all (in which case it will run all necessary commands for you) or you can unpack the tgz (tar/gz) archive, and then the zip contained within as well. This will put all the components into one folder:

Then run the following commands:

1. adb reboot bootloader
2. fastboot flash bootloader bootloader*.img
3. fastboot reboot-bootloader
4. fastboot flash radio radio-mako-m9615a-cefwmazm-2.0.1700.84.img
5. fastboot reboot-bootloader
6. fastboot flash system system.img
7. fastboot flash boot boot.img
8. fastboot format cache
9. fastboot reboot
10. fastboot flash userdata userdata.img **Note: this command will wipe your device (including /sdcard), EVEN if your bootloader is already unlocked.**

*Note:* Instead of unpacking the image*.zip and flashing system and boot manually, you can actually do fastboot update image*.zip - this won't delete data (you would pass a -w flag if you wanted that to happen), but it will re-flash recovery back to stock if you were running a custom one. You can then flash it back, or just use the commands above instead. Either way, the result will be the same.

Comment: went an idiot ... I tried to use the command commands, more for some reason the windows did not recognize, so I used the flash-all.bat factory image that comes in and funcionol perfectly, thanks for your help ^ ^